# How to make a Custom Sorting Function for Dictionary Key Values?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary whose key values are kind of like this,

```
CC-1A
CC-1B
CC-1C
CC-3A
CC-3B
CC-5A
CC-7A
CC-7B
CC-7D
SS-1A
SS-1B
SS-1C
SS-3A
SS-3B
SS-5A
SS-5B

lst = ['CC-1A', 'CC-1B', 'CC-1C', 'CC-3A', 'CC-3B', 'CC-5A', 'CC-7A', 'CC-7B', 
       'CC-7D', 'SS-1A', 'SS-1B', 'SS-1C', 'SS-3A', 'SS-3B', 'SS-5A', 'SS-5B']
d = dict.fromkeys(lst)
```

^Not exactly in this order, but in fact they are all randomly placed in the dictionary as key values.

Now, I want to sort them. If I use the built in function to sort the dictionary, it sorts all the key values according to the order given above.

However, I want the dictionary to be first sorted based upon the values **after the - sign** (i.e. 1A, 1B, 1C etc.) and then based upon the first two characters.

So, for the values given above, following would be my sorted list,

```
    CC-1A
    CC-1B
    CC-1C
    SS-1A
    SS-1B
    SS-1C
    CC-3A
    CC-3B
    SS-3A
    SS-3B
    CC-5A
    and so on
```

1. First, sorting is done based upon the "4th" character in the keys. (that is, 1, 3, etc.)
2. Then sorting is done based upon the last character (i.e. A, B etc.)
3. Then sorting is done based upon the first two characters of the keys (i.e. CC, SS etc.)

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: No, there is no way to do what you're asking for, as you can't have both the order you're describing and the order you're showing in your example. They contradict each other.

Comment: `CC-1A1` wouldn't come before `SS-1A` with your rule

Comment: @KellyBundy how do they contradict? :/ is it still not possible if I know what key I am going to insert into my dictionary? Like, I already have CC-1A, CC-1B, CC-3A, CC-5A and now next item to be inserted is SS-1A, is it possible to insert it between CC-1B and CC-3A?

Comment: Sorting for the thing behin `-` first then what comes before would result in SS-1A, CC-1A1, CC-1A2,C-1B, SS-1B  .. your order is impossible without presorting and applyingsome value based function that already knows about the order you want

Comment: @enke I have modified it to only include CC-1A. I am sorry for that. I get what you are saying.

Comment: Dictionaries are UNORDERED (* insertion ordered is an implementation detail that is guranteed since 3.7) - for their function the order of the keys when printed is absolutely irrelevant - they are a O1 lookup of values.

Comment: @PatrickArtner That sounds really weird. When it got guaranteed, it stopped being an implementation detail.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I understand that they are unordereded and don't really require any sorting. But for my problem, however, I am supposed to print out the "values" against each key of dictionary (but values should be printed in one particular order of the Keys. For example, first the value against "CC-1A" should be printed, and then so on). I would have done it without sorting, however only problem is, I am not aware of the key values beforehand... Which is why I believe sorting the Keys of dictionary would be the first step of mine.

Comment: try `print(  *(di[v] for v in sorted(di, key= lambda x: (x[3],x[4],x[:2]) )), sep="\n")` this will sort by number,m then character then start of key - but is totally different from your "wanted"

Comment: @PatrickArtner worked like a charm! THANK YOU SO MUCH! ^_^

Comment: Suggest you read the [Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "wanted" and your sorting description deviate.

Your "wanted" can be achieved by

```
di = {"CC-1A":"value1","CC-1A":"value2","CC-1B":"value3",
"CC-1C":"value4","CC-3A":"value5","CC-3B":"value6",
"CC-5A":"value7","CC-7A":"value8","CC-7B":"value9",
"CC-7D":"value0","SS-1A":"value11","SS-1B":"value12",
"SS-1C":"value13","SS-3A":"value14","SS-3B":"value15",
"SS-5A":"value16","SS-5B":"value17"}

print(*((v,di[v]) for v in sorted(di, key= lambda x: (x[3], x[:2], x[4]) )), 
      sep="\n")
```

to get

```
('CC-1A', 'value2')
('CC-1B', 'value3')
('CC-1C', 'value4')
('SS-1A', 'value11')
('SS-1B', 'value12')
('SS-1C', 'value13')
('CC-3A', 'value5')
('CC-3B', 'value6')
('SS-3A', 'value14')
('SS-3B', 'value15')
('CC-5A', 'value7')
('SS-5A', 'value16')
('SS-5B', 'value17')
('CC-7A', 'value8')
('CC-7B', 'value9')
('CC-7D', 'value0')
```

which sorts by number (Pos 4 - (1based)), Start (Pos 1+2 (1based)) then letter (Pos 5 (1based))

but that conflicts with

> 1. First, sorting is done based upon the "4th" character in the keys.
>    (that is, 1, 3, etc.)
> 2. Then sorting is done based upon the last character (i.e. A, B etc.)
> 3. Then sorting is done based upon the first two characters of the keys
>    (i.e. CC, SS etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function to build a sorting key that will make the required decomposition of the key strings and return a tuple to sort by.  Then use that function as the key= parameter of the sorted function:

```
D = {'CC-1A': 0, 'CC-1B': 1, 'CC-1C': 2, 'CC-3A': 3, 'CC-3B': 4, 
    'CC-5A': 5, 'CC-7A': 6, 'CC-7B': 7, 'CC-7D': 8, 'SS-1A': 9, 
    'SS-1B': 10, 'SS-1C': 11, 'SS-3A': 12, 'SS-3B': 13, 'SS-5A': 14, 
    'SS-5B': 15}

def sortKey(s):
    L,R = s.split("-",1)
    return (R[:-1],L)

D={k:D[k] for k in sorted(D.keys(),key=sortKey)}

print(D)
{'CC-1A': 0, 
 'CC-1B': 1, 
 'CC-1C': 2, 
 'SS-1A': 9, 
 'SS-1B': 10, 
 'SS-1C': 11, 
 'CC-3A': 3, 
 'CC-3B': 4, 
 'SS-3A': 12, 
 'SS-3B': 13, 
 'CC-5A': 5, 
 'SS-5A': 14, 
 'SS-5B': 15, 
 'CC-7A': 6, 
 'CC-7B': 7, 
 'CC-7D': 8}
```

*If you expect the numbers to eventually go beyond 9 and want a numerical order, then right justify the `R` part in the tuple: e.g. `return (R[:-1].rjust(10),L)`*

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion is to use a nested dictionary, so instead of:

```
my_dict = {'CC-1A1': 2,
           'CC-1A2': 3,
           'CC-1B': 1,
           'CC-1C': 5,
           'SS-1A': 33,
           'SS-1B': 23,
           'SS-1C': 31,
           'CC-3A': 55,
           'CC-3B': 222,
           }
```

you would have something like:

```
my_dict = {'CC': {'1A1': 2, '1A2': 3, '1B': 1, '1C': 5, '3A': 55, '3B': 222},
           'SS': {'1A': 33, '1B': 22, '1C': 31}
           }
```

which would allow you to sort first based on the leading number/characters and then by group. (Actually I think you want this concept reversed based on your question).

Then you can create two lists with your sorted keys/values by doing something like:

```
top_keys = sorted(my_dict)
keys_sorted = []
values_sorted = []

for key in top_keys:
    keys_sorted.append([f"{key}-{k}" for k in my_dict[key].keys()])
    values_sorted.append([v for v in my_dict[key].values()])

flat_keys = [key for sublist in keys_sorted for key in sublist]
flat_values = [value for sublist in values_sorted for value in sublist]
```

Otherwise, you'd have to implement a custom sorting algorithm based first the characters after the `-` and subsequently on the initial characters.

Comment: The approach by @enke is much better :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom function that implements your rule as sorting key:

```
def get_order(tpl):
    s = tpl[0].split('-')
    return (s[1][0], s[0], s[1][1])


out = dict(sorted(d.items(), key=get_order))
```

Output:

```
{'CC-1A': None, 'CC-1B': None, 'CC-1C': None, 'SS-1A': None, 'SS-1B': None, 'SS-1C': None, 'CC-3A': None, 'CC-3B': None, 'SS-3A': None, 'SS-3B': None, 'CC-5A': None, 'SS-5A': None, 'SS-5B': None, 'CC-7A': None, 'CC-7B': None, 'CC-7D': None}
```